# how to check not initialized object in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

I have a graphics object myline. He was maked from class MyLineItem and it's subclassed from QGraphicsLineItem.

Before first initialization I must check if myline is initialized. (if not... do something - initialize it). But nothing works form me. Do you know where is the problem?

In H file i have two constructors:

```
explicit MyLineItem(QGraphicsLineItem *parent = 0);
MyLineItem(const QLineF &line, QGraphicsItem *parent = 0)
```

In my main program is something like this:

```
MyLineItem *myline;

if (myline != 0)
{
    QLineF newLine = QLineF(myline->line().p1(), mouseEvent->scenePos());
    myline->setLine(newLine);
    update();
}
else
{
     myline = new MyLineItem(QLineF(mouseEvent->scenePos(),mouseEvent->scenePos()));
}
```

Problem is, that program still going only into if{}. But in first time they must go into else{} part of code.

I tested `if(myline != NULL), if(myline != 0), if(myline != nullptr)` stil the same. In if part program crashed. Ofcourse.... because object myline is not initialized, because they newer going into else{} part.

Comment: *Where* is `myline` defined? Is it a local variable inside a function? Is it a class member variable? And why don't you just *initialize* it when you define it?

Comment: why don't you initialize...: because line is created after first mouse click. myline is defined in H file as private main class variable.

Comment: But i don't understand why if I make change from if(myline != NULL) to if(myline == NULL), program still go to the if{} block only.

Comment: I recommend you do some research about *constructor member variable initializer lists*. Because that way you can initialize it to `nullptr` when objects of the class is created.

Comment: Just change the first line to `MyLineItem *myline = 0;`

Comment: Super! Thanks. It works! There is maybe some problem (in constructor) and I do "I recommend you do some research..." too. But this is quick help for me at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

1. Modern C++ can practically get rid of usage of raw pointer, particularly with Qt Framework which provides managed pointers QScopedPointer, QSharedPointer...
   and STL library too
2. non-initialized stuff like your MyLineItem *myline  can be catched easily, Compilers as option for detecting them
3. With visual studio at least, you get different result in debug and release mode with un-initialized variable or pointer. In Debug it's generally Zero´ed but not the case in Release, which sometimes explain why code can work in Debug but not in Release